# Inner join in visual basic 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a problem when I run the next query:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Conceptos.Monto_C), Conceptos.Cargo_E FROM  " & _
            "(Conceptos INNER JOIN Empleado ON Conceptos.Cargo_E=Empleado.Cargo_E) " & _
            "WHERE '" & cargo & "' = Empleado.Cargo_E And Conceptos.Tipo_C = asignacion" & _
            "GROUP BY Conceptos.Cargo_E;"
```

The exception says that there is an operator missing from the query in this part:

```
"WHERE '" & cargo & "' = Empleado.Cargo_E And Conceptos.Tipo_C = asignacion"
```

This is in Visual Basic 2010

Edit:
Already resolved it it was supposed to look like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Conceptos.Monto_C), Conceptos.Cargo_E FROM  " & _
            "(Conceptos INNER JOIN Empleado ON Conceptos.Cargo_E=Empleado.Cargo_E) " & _
            "WHERE ('" & cargo & "' = Empleado.Cargo_E) And (Conceptos.Tipo_C = 'asignacion')" & _
            "GROUP BY Conceptos.Cargo_E;"
```

Comment: What is the variable 'cargo' stores?

Comment: a string tht it's added in a textbox

Comment: Can somebody help me, because now how i display the results in a textbox?

Comment: what particular string it stores? I think you're having duplicates in your query.

Comment: This technique you are using -- embedding a user-provided string directly into a SQL statement -- is *bad*. It makes your application vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider what will happen if the cargo variable contains the value `'=''); DROP TABLE Conceptos; --`

Comment: It depends on a previous query that fills that textbox. In which part i's there a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Conceptos.Monto_C), Conceptos.Cargo_E FROM  " & _
            "(Conceptos INNER JOIN Empleado ON Conceptos.Cargo_E=Empleado.Cargo_E) " & _
            "WHERE ('" & cargo & "' = Empleado.Cargo_E) And (Conceptos.Tipo_C = 'asignacion')" & _
            "GROUP BY Conceptos.Cargo_E;"
```